# sql select based on column in another table

Tags: sql

Ok I have two tables.

One table is called Persons and just has columns Pname and Age. (A person's name and their age).
Another table is called Giving and has donor, receiver, and giftname.  (donor and receiver have foreign key constraints referencing persons.pname).

I need to find the names of all people who donated a gift to someone with a different age.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, also adding some sample data and then the desired result would be helpful.

Comment: This requires a couple of inner joins with a where filter - are you familiar with SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  Giving.donor
FROM Giving
INNER JOIN Persons AS donor ON Giving.donor=donor.Pname
INNER JOIN Persons AS receiver ON Giving.receiver=receiver.Pname
WHERE donor.Age<>receiver.Age
```

Comment: On which database? This should work at least on MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, PQ. Any more Info in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the donor age has to be different then the receiver age, then try this:

```
SELECT pd.pname 
FROM Persons pd
INNER JOIN giving g
ON pd.pname = g.donor
INNER JOIN persons pr
ON pr.pname = g.receiver AND pr.age != pd.age
```